# Ember.js: Accepted best practices for communication between child and parent components

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to ember.js and one of the things I've found really difficult to understand is the 2-way communication of data and events between parent and child components.

I managed to solve a simpler problem in regards to maintaining a list of items, keeping track of which one was active, and changing the active child from the parent component.  The pattern is summed up in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/kugusu/10/edit?html,js,output).

I'm wondering, is this the best approach to solving my problem ?  Despite ember being 'highly opinionated' I find there are so many different ways to achieve the same thing so just looking for some reassurance or redirection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practices can be summarized as 'data down', 'actions up'. You want to pass data down to your component and actions up to the parent as much as possible to isolate the child component from the parent so it can be used anywhere. Avoid sending data up through two way bindings as that will no longer be the default in Ember 2.0. (Bindings will be one way by default.)

The main change to your jsbin I would make is instead of sending parentCtrl=this in your template, I would send down itemSelected=itemSelected. Then in your item component:

```
isActive: Ember.computed('itemSelected', function() {
    if (this.get('itemSelected') !== null) {
        return this.get('itemSelected.description');
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}),
```

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav, good to know I'm on the right track and thanks for clarifying how to maximize isolation